How to subtract times stored as strings in Oracle
I have a scenario where I need to subtract one time from another.
In table column data type is varchar2
event_time_1 varchar2(10)
event_time_2 varchar2(10)

Data in table
event_time_1  event_time_2
10:01         10:04
10:02         10:06 

Now I need to calculate event_time_1  - event_time_2, but as both of them are varchar2, how can I achieve it?

Can you clarify what the expected result is? Another string, containing the number of seconds between the two times? How should it be formatted? In the example you give, this would be negative, is that correct, or a mistake in the example?

How would your desired output look like? What did you already try?

Also what happens if the times are on different days - I guess a negative result might indicate that (or positive, in your example), but is the gap always going to be less than 24 hours anyway? And are the times always in the same time zone? (This is why it usually doesn't make sense to just store a time - storing a complete datetime value (as a date/timestamp) would make the calculation easier and clearer.

Convert the strings to dates and then subtract to get either an interval or else the number of days difference (which you can multiple by 24*60 to get minutes):
SELECT event_time_1,
       event_time_2,
       (
         TO_DATE(event_time_2, 'HH24:MI')
         - TO_DATE(event_time_1, 'HH24:MI')
       ) DAY TO SECOND AS interval_diff,
       (
         TO_DATE(event_time_2, 'HH24:MI')
         - TO_DATE(event_time_1, 'HH24:MI')
       ) AS days_diff,
       (
         TO_DATE(event_time_2, 'HH24:MI')
         - TO_DATE(event_time_1, 'HH24:MI')
       ) * 24 * 60 AS minutes_diff
FROM   table_name

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  event_time_1 varchar2(10),
  event_time_2 varchar2(10)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (event_time_1, event_time_2)
SELECT '10:01', '10:04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10:02', '10:06' FROM DUAL

Outputs:



EVENT_TIME_1
EVENT_TIME_2
INTERVAL_DIFF
DAYS_DIFF
MINUTES_DIFF




10:01
10:04
+00 00:03:00.000000
.002083333333333333333333333333333333333333
3


10:02
10:06
+00 00:04:00.000000
.002777777777777777777777777777777777777778
4



fiddle

The difference is second
DECLARE
 v_diff NUMBER;
BEGIN
 .....
v_diff := round((to_date (event_time_2, 'MI:SS') - to_date (event_time_1, 'MI:SS'))*86400);
...
END ;


DATE data type in Oracle containes 7 bytes representing centuries, years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds. VARCHAR2 data type could be converted into DATE using To_Date() function. Substracting date from another date gets you the result in days. Resulting days could be calculated into hours, minutes or seconds:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select 1 "ID", '11.04.2024' "DT_1", '10:01' "ET_1", '11.04.2024' "DT_2", '10:04' "ET_2" From Dual Union All
          Select 2 "ID", '10.04.2024' "DT_1", '10:02' "ET_1", '12.04.2024' "DT_2", '10:06' "ET_2" From Dual 
        )

--    S Q L :
Select    ID,
          DT_1 || ' ' || ET_1 || ':00' "DT_ET_1", 
          DT_2 || ' ' || ET_2 || ':00' "DT_ET_2",
          Round(To_Date(DT_2 || ' ' || ET_2 || ':00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - 
          To_Date(DT_1 || ' ' || ET_1 || ':00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 9) "DIFF_DAYS", 
          --
          Round(( To_Date(DT_2 || ' ' || ET_2 || ':00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - 
            To_Date(DT_1 || ' ' || ET_1 || ':00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ) * 24, 4) "DIFF_HOURS", 
          --
          Round(( To_Date(DT_2 || ' ' || ET_2 || ':00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - 
            To_Date(DT_1 || ' ' || ET_1 || ':00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ) * 24 * 60, 4) "DIFF_MINS", 
          --
          Round(( To_Date(DT_2 || ' ' || ET_2 || ':00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - 
            To_Date(DT_1 || ' ' || ET_1 || ':00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ) * 24 *60 * 60, 4) "DIFF_SECS" 
From      tbl

/*    --  R e s u l t : 
ID   DT_ET_1                DT_ET_2             DIFF_DAYS   DIFF_HOURS DIFF_MINS DIFF_SECS
--   -------------------    ------------------- ----------- ---------- --------- ---------
 1   11.04.2024 10:01:00    11.04.2024 10:04:00 0,002083333     0,0500         3       180
 2   10.04.2024 10:02:00    12.04.2024 10:06:00 2,002777778    48,0667      2884    173040  */


I did it in this way
 CAST(replace(event_time, ':', '') AS NUMBER) AS n1
 CAST(replace(event_time, ':', '') AS NUMBER) AS n2

Then perform minus n2 - n1
